# create a network between to ubuntu and localhost

Tags: ubuntu

I want create a network between two ubuntu on virtual machine and localhost on windows.
I know set network vmware on host-only for connect to localhostT.but I want two virtual machine  connected together with NAT.

Answer (score 0):

the virtual machines should appear as different hosts in your network, therefore you should be able to simply use the ip-address(es). (depending on the network settings in virtualbox)

I'm not entirely sure though.

 You can use

```
ifconfig
```

to see what the address of localhost is or

```
nmap -sL <network>.*
```

to look up all computers.